# Are named capture groups supported? If so, how to engage?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I understand that VSCode uses the JavaScript regex engine for its functionality.

The latest JavaScript specification allows for named capture groups to be used.

However, I am at a loss in understanding whether this is enabled in VSCode v1.43?

I am using the following notations in the general find command:

`(?<name-of-capture>pattern to find)( other stuff )(\k<name-of-capture>)`

`(?<name-of-capture>pattern to find)( other stuff )(\g<name-of-capture>)`

I have also used the combinations of `\k'name'` and `\g'name'` and these have no effect.

If anyone has insights into this I would appreciate to hear.

Comment: What exactly are you trying? Please paste the regex, replacement string (if any) and the text you are searching against with the list of expected matches/results

Comment: Judging by [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/88793), it doesn't look like it.

Comment: If you want to use an inline backreference, it works, `(?<group>[a-z]+) \d+ \k<group>` matches `abc 1 abc`. But `$<group>` replacement does not work, probably, due to bug referred to by @JW. .NET-style replacement backreference, `${group}`, does not work either.

Comment: If my answer does not help you solve the issue, please consider updating the question.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use an inline backreference, they work in VSCode.

```
(?<group>[a-z]+) \d+ \k<group>
```

matches `abc 1 abc`.

However, new JavaScript-like `$<group>` replacement does not work, .NET-style replacement backreference, `${group}`, does not work either, probably, due to [the issue referred to by @JW](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/88793).

**NOTE**: They say they need 20 votes on the issue and there are **3 days to go** before they close the issue and turn down the suggestion to introduce backreferences in replacement. If you want this feature to be implemented, please consider voting for that issue.